# Perhaps I fundamentally misunderstand indentation in python? - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, syntax, process

This code gives me an indentation error on checks. I get that this happens often, but the instance is in between two for loops that exist because I need to reference two different lists.

I do not even have the data set made yet, but it should report that the syntax is correct at least. The code is fairly simple. I want to automate package placement in a building and I want to do so by taking the biggest packages and putting them in place with the least amount of room where it would still fit.

All inputs that I used so far are dictionaries because I need to know which shelf I am referring too. I am this close to turning it to lists and being extremely strict about formatting.

```
inv = maxkey["Inventory"]
```

is the line where the mistake happens. I do not know how to fix it. Should I use lists for this project instead? Is there a flaw in the logic? Is there a parentheses I forgot? Please let me know if this is just an oversight on my part. Please contact me for further details.

```py
def loadOrder(inProd, units, loc, pref, shelves):
items = len(inProd)
while items > 0
    # What is the biggest package in the list?
    mxw = 0 # Frontal area trackers
    BoxId = {} # Identifies what is being selected
    for p in inProd:
        if p["Height"]*p["Width"] > mxw:
            mxw = p["Width"]*p["Height"]
            BoxId = p
        else:
            pass

    # What is the location with the least amount of space?
    maxi = 0.001
    maxkey = {}

    for key in loc:
        if key["Volume Efficiency"] > maxi and key["Width"] > mxw/BoxId["Height"]:
            maxi = key["Volume Efficiency"]
            maxkey = key
        else:
            pass
    maxkey["Inventory"].append(BoxId)
    weight = 0
    volTot = 0
    usedL = 0
    inv = maxkey["Inventory"]
    for k in inv:
        weight = k['Weight']+weight
        vol = k['Height']*k['Width']*k['Depth']+volTot
        usedL = k['Width']+usedL

    maxkey["Volume Efficiency"] = volTot/(maxkey['Height']*maxkey['Weight']*maxkey['Depth'])
    maxkey['Width Remaining'] = usedL
    maxkey['Capacity Remaining'] = weight
    del inProd[BoxId]
    items = len(inProd)

return [inProd, units, loc, pref, shelves]
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to include it was Python. I will add it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Indentation in a function definition should be like:

```
def function-name():
    <some code>
    <return something>
```

Also, you have missed `:` after while loop condition.

It shoulde be `while items > 0:`

Comment: I went through it again and reindented the whole code. Should tab not be used anymore? For some reason, at that line it expects me to continue in the else statement when I want to move on.

Answer (score 1):

And you should not mixing the use of **tabs** and **spaces** for indentation.
The standard way for indentation is 4 spaces.
you can see more in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id17).

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why my interpretor does that. I always tab but often it switches to spaces without prompting